How can I install a specific version of google chrome in my centos?
I need to add a command in my docker file which would install a specific version of google chrome.
FROM centos:7

MAINTAINER The CentOS Project <cloud-ops@centos.org>

LABEL Vendor="CentOS" \
      License=GPLv2 \
      Version=2.4.6-40

RUN yum -y install wget epel-release
RUN yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs update && \
      yum -y --setopt=tsflags=nodocs install httpd && \
      yum clean all

RUN yum -y update && yum -y install git

RUN yum -y install \
      https://repo.ius.io/ius-release-el7.rpm \
      https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm

RUN yum install yum-utils

RUN yum -y install httpd-devel --skip-broken\
      zlib-devel \
      bzip2-devel \
      openssl-devel \
      ncurses-devel \
      sqlite-devel \
      readline \
      https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm \
      python36u \
      python36u-pip \
      python36u-devel \
      uwsgi \
      uwsgi-plugin-python36u \
      python-pip \
      mysql-devel \
      unzip

RUN yum -y group install "Development Tools"

RUN  yum clean all;

RUN yum -y install gcc

RUN pip3.6 install --upgrade pip && pip3.6 install boto && pip3.6 install boto3
RUN yum -y install https://centos7.iuscommunity.org/ius-release.rpm python36u python36u-devel python36u-pip
RUN pip3.6 install pathlib

#INSTALL GOOGLE CHROME
RUN yum -y update; yum clean all
RUN yum -y install mesa-dri-drivers libexif libcanberra-gtk2 libcanberra; yum clean all

ADD https://dl.google.com/linux/direct/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm /root/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm

RUN yum -y install /root/google-chrome-stable_current_x86_64.rpm; yum clean all
RUN dbus-uuidgen > /etc/machine-id

#INSTALL CHROMEDRIVER
RUN CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION="114.0.5735.90" && \
    mkdir -p /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    curl -sS -o /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip https://storage.googleapis.com/chrome-for-testing-public/122.0.6261.57/linux64/chromedriver-linux64.zip && \
    unzip -qq /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip -d /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION && \
    rm /tmp/chromedriver_linux64.zip && \
    chmod +x /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver-linux64 && \
    ln -fs /opt/chromedriver-$CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION/chromedriver-linux64 /usr/local/bin/chromedriver


RUN /bin/pip3.6 install django==2.1
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install channels==2.2.0
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install djangorestframework==3.10.2
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install django-cors-headers==3.1.0
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install mysqlclient
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install mysql-connector-python
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install djangorestframework-jwt==1.11.0
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install Pillow channels_redis==2.4.0 pymysql
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install boto3==1.11.0
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install django==2.1
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install python-decouple
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install selenium==3.141.0
RUN /bin/pip3.6 install chromedriver-autoinstaller

RUN mkdir -p /web/www/Django
COPY Django/ /web/www/Django
COPY start.sh /start.sh
COPY settings.ini /web/www/Django/WhatsappAdmin/settings.ini
COPY requirements.txt web/www/Django/WhatsappAdmin/requirements.txt

RUN /bin/pip3.6 install -r /web/www/Django/WhatsappAdmin/requirements.txt

RUN chmod +x /start.sh

RUN yum install -y uwsgi-logger-file uwsgi-plugin-python36u --skip-broken

RUN touch /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "[uwsgi]" > /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "socket = /run/whatsappuwsgi/uwsgi.sock" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "chmod-socket = 775" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "chdir = /web/www/Django/WhatsappAdmin" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "master = true" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "module = WhatsappAdmin.wsgi:application" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "uid = uwsgi" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "gid = uwsgi" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "processes = 1" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "threads = 1" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini
RUN echo "plugins = python36u,logfile" >> /etc/uwsgi.d/whatsapp.ini

RUN mkdir -p /run/whatsappuwsgi/
RUN chmod 2775 /run/whatsappuwsgi
RUN touch /run/whatsappuwsgi/uwsgi.sock

RUN chgrp -R 0 /web/www/Django/WhatsappAdmin/* /start.sh /run /run/whatsappuwsgi/* /var/lib /var/log /usr/sbin/uwsgi \
      && chmod -R g=u /web/www/Django/WhatsappAdmin/* /start.sh /run /run/whatsappuwsgi/* /usr/sbin/uwsgi  /var/lib /var/log

EXPOSE 5000

CMD ["/start.sh"]

I do have the command to install which would install google chrome, but that chrome version is not compatible with my googlechrome driver(version 114).
Any suggestions?
Thanks
I have the link for google chrome driver for selenium for version 114. Since, I couldn't find version 124 chromedriver so, I have to install chrome browser for version 114.

Somewhat different angle, but: if you use playwright rather than selenium, you don't need to manually install these things.
